# Is there a way to move the slight indent of this <marquee> CSS alternative?

Tags: html, css

Since the `<marquee>` HTML tag is deprecated, I'll use a CSS alternative. But, it comes to the left, but I want the text going to the right. Here's the `<marquee>` CSS alternative with a bit of styling. I've tried swapping the values, which does make it go to the right, but it starts *near* the end of the text, but not at the end, which the actual `<marquee>`. Here are both:
To the left:

> ```css
> p {
>         color: darkblue;
>         font: xx-large sans-serif;
>         white-space: nowrap;
>         animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
>       }
>       @keyframes marquee {
>         100% {
>           transform: translateX(-100%)
>         }
>         0% {
>           transform: translateX(100%);
>         }
>       }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
> ```

To the right, but not from directly the end:

> ```css
> p {
>         color: darkblue;
>         font: xx-large sans-serif;
>         white-space: nowrap;
>         animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
>       }
>       @keyframes marquee {
>         100% {
>           transform: translateX(100%)
>         }
>         0% {
>           transform: translateX(-100%);
>         }
>       }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Found out. All I had to do was use `left: -200` (but it may be more or less than -200 for other lengths of text) and `position: relative;` in CSS applied to the `<p>` tag on the one going to the right. It was that simple. ;-;